# why create a unique clustered index only to drop the table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Here is the code I am trying to figure out why the developer use this code in a stored procedure.  Why create a unique clustered index on a temp table then drop the table?  This index is not used anywhere else in the stored procedure either.  Why would one do this?

```
CREATE TABLE #L130BI3KBMDE (location_subgrouping1 uniqueidentifier not null)
go
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX  XPK#L130BI3KBMDE ON #L130BI3KBMDE(location_subgrouping1)
go
DROP TABLE #L130BI3KBMDE
go
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance
Dean-O

Comment: Creation and immediately deletion isn't strange? Where are you get this code?

Comment: They're an idiot? Looks like some code got deleted but they missed some pieces?

Comment: I got this from a vendor application that has a built in reporting tool... instead of using Crystal Reports... so I turned on SQL profiler and captured the sql when running one of their reports... there are several of these at the start of the sql captured in the sql profiler.  It did not make sense to create 3 or 4 of these and not use them in the SP... so I thought I would ask if that was a SP trick for efficiency or something

Comment: It could be poorly written dynamic sql. For instance, there might be additional tsql between `CREATE UNIQUE...` and `DROP TABLE...` that is present under different conditions.  Not that that would excuse the vendor.

Comment: To let it worst it's a clustered index over a **uniqueidentifier**. Well, why create a table to just drop it? The table is supposed to serve a purpose as is the index over the table. I guess a lot of original code is missing and the answer is in that code we are not seeing.